# What does the if statement in the merge sort of wikipedia C iteration version mean?

Tags: c

I found that the merge sort of C version in Wikipedia, such as:

```
int min(int x, int y) {
    return x < y ? x : y;
}
void merge_sort(int arr[], int len) {
    int *a = arr;
    int *b = (int *) malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    int seg, start;
    for (seg = 1; seg < len; seg += seg) {
        for (start = 0; start < len; start += seg * 2) {
            int low = start, mid = min(start + seg, len), high = min(start + seg * 2, len);
            int k = low;
            int start1 = low, end1 = mid;
            int start2 = mid, end2 = high;
            while (start1 < end1 && start2 < end2)
                b[k++] = a[start1] < a[start2] ? a[start1++] : a[start2++];
            while (start1 < end1)
                b[k++] = a[start1++];
            while (start2 < end2)
                b[k++] = a[start2++];
        }
        int *temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (a != arr) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        b = a;
    }
    free(b);
}
```

I don't know why there is an `if` statement, what does it mean?

```
    if (a != arr) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        b = a;
    }
```

I think the `b` is gonna to be freed, so why to operate `b`? Why not just `free(b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of the loop, `a` is the array to be merged and `b` is the array to merge into.
At the end of the loop, `a` and `b` are swapped in preparation for the next iteration.

This means that after the loop, `a` points to the sorted result, but that can be either the input array or the locally allocated one (which must be freed or there will be a memory leak).

When necessary, the conditional arranges things by copying the result, and ensuring that `b` points to the locally allocated memory so `free(b)` will free the memory allocated by the function.

It could also be written

```
if (a != arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        arr[i] = a[i];
    free(a);
} else {
    free(b);
}
```

Introducing another variable would make it less confusing, in my opinion:

```
void merge_sort(int arr[], int len) {
    int *local_memory = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    int *a = arr;
    int *b = local_memory;
    int seg, start;
    for (seg = 1; seg < len; seg += seg) {
        /* ... */
        int *temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (a != arr) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            arr[i] = a[i];
    }
    free(local_memory);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this algorithm, you allocate some memory

```
int *b = (int *) malloc(len * sizeof(int));
```

This memory must be freed at the end of the algorithm (or you will have a memory leak).
However, in the first `for` loop you switch `a` and `b`:

```
int *temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Since we don't know if there has been a odd number of step in the algorithm, you don't know which variable point to the address of the memory allocated at the beginning. 
This last `if` permits to determine which variable contains the address of the allocated memory. Remember that when you write `free(b)`, you don't free the variable `b` which is a pointer (i.e. a variable of size depending from you system architecture 4 bytes in 32bits systems, 8 bytes in 64bits systems, ...), you free the memory at the address pointed by `b`.

So, before the `if`, you have two cases,

1. `a` has the address of the allocated memory and `b` is equal to `arr`
2. `a` is equal to `arr` and `b` has the address of the allocated memory

Comment: Also, in case that `a` is not the original array, the data needs to be copied back from the allocated array into the original array before the allocated array can be freed. Otherwise, the original array would be left in the state before the last merge.